# Why HttpServletRequest truncates url input on a # character?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-web

The following servlet reads the url path parameter.
Problem: if the input contains special chars, eg I discovered `#`, then the string is truncated!

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {    
    @GetMapping("/hash")
    @ApiIgnore
    public String hash(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String pw = req.getPathInfo(); //asdfgh
    }
}

`localhost:8080/hash/asdfgh#jkl`
```

Question: how can I natively pass through the input parameter?

Comment: try using regex in controller path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part starting from the `#` is not send to/received by to your servlet.
It is an information used only from the client side (browser) and **doesn't make
part of a URI**.

The [RFC2396](http://From%20RFC2396) states indeed :

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
>   identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
>   the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional
>   reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the
>   retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not
>   part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

Comment: So there is clearly no chance to read the parameter entirely from serverside?

Comment: With the hash no. But if it matters for you, why not pass the information as a parameter ?